# java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException in eclipse

Tags: android, eclipse

I am creating two array lists to hold obstacles for a game the lists are:

```
ArrayList<Obstacle>  TopWalls = null;
ArrayList<Obstacle>  BottomWalls = null;
```

I then populate them within a method called prep screen:

```
public void prepScreen(int width, int height){
ScreenH = height;
Num = (width)/center.getWidth()+4;
TopWalls = new ArrayList<Obstacle>();
BottomWalls = new ArrayList<Obstacle>();

for (int i=0;i<Num+1;i++){
    Obstacle TO = new Obstacle(center, width+50+center.getWidth()*i,0);
    TO.setManager (this);
    TopWalls.add(TO);

    Obstacle BO = new Obstacle(center, width+50+center.getWidth()*i,0);
    BO.setManager (this);
    TopWalls.add(BO);

    }   

        GenerateObstacles();

}
```

However when i run the code the Log Cat tells me that there is a java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException

LOG CAT:

```
04-10 14:17:54.062: E/AndroidRuntime(1301): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
04-10 14:17:54.062: E/AndroidRuntime(1301): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.deepseadiver/com.example.deepseadiver.Game}: java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Invalid index 0, size is 0
04-10 14:17:54.062: E/AndroidRuntime(1301):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2185)
04-10 14:17:54.062: E/AndroidRuntime(1301):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2210)
04-10 14:17:54.062: E/AndroidRuntime(1301):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:142)
04-10 14:17:54.062: E/AndroidRuntime(1301):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1208)
04-10 14:17:54.062: E/AndroidRuntime(1301):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
04-10 14:17:54.062: E/AndroidRuntime(1301):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
04-10 14:17:54.062: E/AndroidRuntime(1301):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4931)
04-10 14:17:54.062: E/AndroidRuntime(1301):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
04-10 14:17:54.062: E/AndroidRuntime(1301):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
04-10 14:17:54.062: E/AndroidRuntime(1301):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:791)
04-10 14:17:54.062: E/AndroidRuntime(1301):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:558)
04-10 14:17:54.062: E/AndroidRuntime(1301):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
04-10 14:17:54.062: E/AndroidRuntime(1301): Caused by: java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Invalid index 0, size is 0
04-10 14:17:54.062: E/AndroidRuntime(1301):     at java.util.ArrayList.throwIndexOutOfBoundsException(ArrayList.java:251)
04-10 14:17:54.062: E/AndroidRuntime(1301):     at java.util.ArrayList.get(ArrayList.java:304)
04-10 14:17:54.062: E/AndroidRuntime(1301):     at com.example.deepseadiver.Obstaclemanager.GenerateObstacles(Obstaclemanager.java:87)
04-10 14:17:54.062: E/AndroidRuntime(1301):     at com.example.deepseadiver.Obstaclemanager.prepScreen(Obstaclemanager.java:62)
04-10 14:17:54.062: E/AndroidRuntime(1301):     at com.example.deepseadiver.GamePanel.<init>(GamePanel.java:40)
04-10 14:17:54.062: E/AndroidRuntime(1301):     at com.example.deepseadiver.Game.onCreate(Game.java:94)
04-10 14:17:54.062: E/AndroidRuntime(1301):     at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5008)
04-10 14:17:54.062: E/AndroidRuntime(1301):     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1079)
04-10 14:17:54.062: E/AndroidRuntime(1301):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2139)
04-10 14:17:54.062: E/AndroidRuntime(1301):     ... 11 more
```

The prepScreen method is then being run by the game panel class:

```
OM.prepScreen(ScreenWidth, Screenheight);
```

Obstaclemanager.java:

```
    package com.example.deepseadiver;

import java.util.ArrayList;

import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.graphics.Canvas;

public class Obstaclemanager {

    Bitmap center;
    //Variable for the height of the submarine
    int subHeight;
    int Num;
    int ScreenH;
    int dl;
    int TargetY =-1;
    int dpos;
    public GamePanel gamePanel;

    ArrayList<Obstacle>  TopWalls = null;
    ArrayList<Obstacle>  BottomWalls = null;

    public Obstaclemanager(Bitmap decodeResource, GamePanel gamePanel) {
        //set center variable to the value passed into the method 
        center = decodeResource;
        //set gamePanel variable to the value passed into the method
        this.gamePanel = gamePanel;
    }

    //Method gets the height of the submarine
    void setSubH(int h){
        subHeight = h;
    }

    //Method to calculate how many obstacles to draw on screen and create them
    public void prepScreen(int width, int height){
        //Sets variable to the value passed into method
        ScreenH = height;
        //Sets the Num variable based on the width of the Background image 4 is added for good measure
        Num = (width)/center.getWidth()+4;
        //Sets the top and bottom walls to be an array of obstacles
        TopWalls = new ArrayList<Obstacle>();
        BottomWalls = new ArrayList<Obstacle>();
            //For loop from 0 to the Num value
            for (int i=0;i<Num+1;i++){
                //TO (Top Obstacles) are created
                Obstacle TO = new Obstacle(center, width+50+center.getWidth()*i,0);
                //Obstacles are set
                TO.setManager (this);
                //Obstacles are added to the TopWalls array 
                TopWalls.add(TO);

                //BO (Bottom Obstacles) are created
                Obstacle BO = new Obstacle(center, width+50+center.getWidth()*i,0);
                //Obstacles are set
                BO.setManager (this);
                //Obstacles are added to the BottomWalls array 
                TopWalls.add(BO);

            }   
            GenerateObstacles();

    }
    //Method to generate the obstacles
    private void GenerateObstacles() {
        //h variable is set from the value of half the background bitmap
        int h = center.getHeight()/2;
        //sets the dl varible to the screen height variable
        dl = ScreenH;
        //sets the dpos variable to half the screen height so the center horozontal portion of the screen
        dpos = ScreenH/2;
        //sets a new dl variable whose values is 3/5 ths of the screen for when obstacles are placed
        int new_dl = ScreenH*3/5;
        //inc is set based on the screen height minus by the new_dl varable this is then divided by the Num variable which holds the number of obstacles 
        int inc = (dl-new_dl)/Num;
        //For loop from 0 to the Num value
        for (int i=0;i<Num+1;i++){
            //dl is set on its original value minus the value of inc
            dl = dl - inc;
            //h is set to half the height of an obstacle
            h = TopWalls.get(i).getBitmap().getHeight()/2;
            //TopWalls obstacles are positioned
            TopWalls.get(i).setY(dpos -dl/2-h);
            //BottomWalls obstacles are psitioned
            BottomWalls.get(i).setY(dpos +dl/2+h);
        }
    }

    //Method to draw to canvas
    public void draw(Canvas canvas){
        //For loop from 0 to the Num value
        for (int i=0;i<Num+1;i++){
            //TopWalls are drawn to canvas
            TopWalls.get(i).draw(canvas);
            //BottomWalls are drawn to canvas
            BottomWalls.get(i).draw(canvas);
        }
    }

    //Method to update the canvas
    public void update(float dt){
        //For loop from 0 to the Num value
        for (int i=0;i<Num+1;i++){
            //TopWalls are updated
            TopWalls.get(i).update(dt, true);
            //BottomWalls are updated
            BottomWalls.get(i).update(dt, false);
        }
    }


}
```

I have honestly been looking at this for about 3 hours and cannot figure out why this is happening any help or advice is much appreciated.

Comment: 04-10 14:17:54.062: E/AndroidRuntime(1301):     at com.example.deepseadiver.Obstaclemanager.GenerateObstacles(Obstaclemanager.java:87) 

So which line is line 87 in your source code?

Comment: line 87 is the final "}" in the prep screen method

Comment: post GenerateObstacles

Comment: Line 87 in Obstaclemanager.java man, do you even read? A `}` cannot ever throw an exception.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your problem is this line `for (int i=0;i<Num+1;i++){`

you are going from `0` to `Num + 1` when there are only `Num` elements

Comment: Thank you so much you've just saved me hours more of searching